# Js: slideToggle() How to use it properly to show and hide a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

I have this function

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".slidingDiv").hide();
$('.toggle-next-div').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
$(this).next().slideToggle();
});
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="toggle-next-div">Map</a>
<div class="slidingDiv">
<strong>Content</strong>
</div>
```

Now I need to add a link to hide the div inside the div itself (i need "close button" por the pop up window).

It seems I can't use the same function to close the div like this

```
<div class="slidingDiv">
<a href="#" class="toggle-next-div">Close</a>// it doesn't work why?
<strong>Content</strong>
</div>
```

How do I close close the window with a link "close" inside the div?

Comment: In that case you should use `.closest()` or `.parent()` method, `$(this).closest('.slidingDiv').slideUp()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change the close div class then use the javascript code
    
    Close// it doesn't work why?
    **Content**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();

    $('.toggle-next-div').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });

    //newly added code for close button
    $('.toggle-next-div2').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
     $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(".toggle-next-div").click(function(){
    $(this).parents('.slidingDiv').slideUp();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nKzXJ/1/